# why I can't use dark mode?

Tags: web

I have issue to test the website in dark mode and sometimes some of the customers using dark mode. My question is that how can I see my website in dark mode?

I tried google chrome Canary and force dark mode but still I see the white background on my website while customers screenshots are black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh/related

This turned my website backgrounds to dark, but the chromes settings page and webstore background is still left unaffected, they still appear white. 
I guess it works with websites only.

Comment: Your welcome and thanks for the upvote but could you please mark the answer as correct, that will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

1- Go to chrome://flags

2- In Search Input Type dark

3- Choose "Force Dark Mode for Web Contents"

4- Enable It.

[image]

5- ReLunch your Browser